# Can't ping LAN machines while on wired connection

Tags: networking, router, ping, dd-wrt

I have weird situation where a single machine on my home network can't access another. The network is provided by TP-Link WR841ND router to following machines:

- A - 192.168.1.117 - Win8.1 machine, wired connection,
- B - 192.168.1.200 - Ubuntu 12.04 server machine, wired connection,
- C - 192.168.1.111 - Macbook, wireless connection,
- D - 192.168.1.210 - Raspberry Pi, wireless connection.

The problem is that A and B can't ping each other, both with `Destination host unreachable` error.

- A can ping C and D.
- B can ping C and D.
- C can ping A, B, D.
- D can ping A, B, C.

If I take wireless dongle from D and use it on A, everything suddenly works - it's only when both A and B are connected via wired connection the problems arise.

`arp -a` on box A doesn't list B:

`Interface: 192.168.1.117 --- 0xa
  Internet Address      Physical Address   Type
  192.168.1.1           *mac-address*     dynamic
  192.168.1.111         *mac-address*     dynamic
  192.168.1.210         *mac-address*     dynamic`

`arp -a` on box B lists A, but with `<incomplete>` where mac addresses of other devices are:

`A (192.168.1.117) at <incomplete> on eth0
C (192.168.1.111) at *mac-address* [ether] on eth0
router (192.168.1.1) at *mac-address* [ether] on eth0
D (192.168.1.210) at *mac-address* [ether] on eth0`

`arp -a` on box C lists everything:

`router (192.168.1.1) at *mac-address* on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
A (192.168.1.117) at *mac-address* on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
B (192.168.1.200) at *mac-address* on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
D (192.168.1.210) at *mac-address* on en0 ifscope [ethernet]`

The router is running  DD-WRT v24-sp2 (06/23/14) firmware. Resetting factory settings didn't help, neither did disabling SPI firewall, toggling AP isolation on or off, or poking other buttons in frustration.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the revalant parts of IPCONFIG on the windows computer and IFCONFIG on the Linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be bug in DD-WRT router firmware. Appears that [this old bug](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=681495) is back in builds dated after 29.03.2014

Comment: Did upgrading the firmware fix it?

Answer (score 0):

On the router, you may want to check that both wired and wireless connection are on the same firewall zone (lan) and that both wired connection are on the same vlan, inside the lan firewall zone.

You may want to check one computer didn't ban the other automatically for some reason (aggressive blocking policy from some security solutions), did you try pinging machine B from A when running in safe mode with networking to exclude third services on the windows machine ? Did you try disabling firewall completely on both to test ?

This is not a strict answer, just some paths to poke on if you didn't already.